# (180 ringning)No ringing tone while connecting call android pjsip (pjsua2)

Tags: android, pjsip

I have implemented a project for VOIP using PJSIP(PJSUA2).

Everything is fine, but I am not hearing ringing sound when I am calling some one. But other end, he is receiving call.

Here, We can not judge that call is connecting to other one.

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generate tone by yourself. You can use android.media.ToneGenerator. Something like this:

```
ToneGenerator toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 100);
toneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_NETWORK_USA_RINGBACK, 1000);
```

**EDIT**

You can get CallInfo in notifyCallState.

```
CallInfo ci = call.getInfo();
if (ci.getState() == pjsip_inv_state.PJSIP_INV_STATE_EARLY 
    && ci.getRole() == pjsip_role_e.PJSIP_ROLE_UAC 
    && ci.getLastReason().equals("Ringing")) {
     toneGeneratorHelper.startRingBack();
} else {
  toneGeneratorHelper.stopRingBack();
}
```

And for repeating tone you can use handler with postDelayed. Create helper class for this.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes, I used it. but how to get the 180 from CallInfo. and Tone is not repeating for no of times(loop).

Comment: I did it yesterday only. Your are answer is correct and accepted. Thank you buddy. Let's be friends, you gave me reply many times.

Answer (score 3):

The better way to do this is to use `pjsua2` library. With this I mean to skip `Android API` and do as following:

```
import org.pjsip.pjsua2.ToneDesc;
import org.pjsip.pjsua2.ToneDescVector;

private ToneDesc toneDesc;
private org.pjsip.pjsua2.ToneGenerator toneGenerator;
private ToneDescVector toneDescVector;

public class RINGBACK_TONES {
        public final static int kSPRingbackFrequency1 = 440,
                kSPRingbackFrequency2 = 480,
                kSPRingbackOnDuration = 1000,
                kSPRingbackOffDuration = 4000,
                kSPRingbackCount = 1,
                kSPRingbackInterval = 4000;
    }

protected synchronized void startRingbackTone() {

        toneDesc = new ToneDesc();
        toneGenerator = new org.pjsip.pjsua2.ToneGenerator();
        toneDescVector = new ToneDescVector();

        toneDesc.setFreq1((short) RINGBACK_TONES.kSPRingbackFrequency1);
        toneDesc.setFreq2((short) RINGBACK_TONES.kSPRingbackFrequency2);
        toneDesc.setOn_msec((short) RINGBACK_TONES.kSPRingbackOnDuration);
        toneDesc.setOff_msec((short) RINGBACK_TONES.kSPRingbackOffDuration);

        toneDescVector.add(toneDesc);

        try {
            toneGenerator.createToneGenerator();
            toneGenerator.play(toneDescVector, true);
            toneGenerator.startTransmit(Endpoint.audDevManager().getPlaybackDevMedia());

        } catch (Exception ex) { }
}

protected synchronized void stopRingbackTone() {

    try {
        if (toneGenerator != null)
            toneGenerator.stop();
        toneGenerator = null;

    } catch (Exception ex) { }

}
```

Comment: if we are using pjsua2, this is the best method we can do. No need of using android api

Answer (score 0):

you can use Media player and play your custom tone in loop.

set AudioManager mode to MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION